# Redux doesn't fetch array after action has dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm looking to append the data in the `UPLOAD_IMAGE` to `GET_IMAGES`. Without having to re-rerendering the component. Or in other words, without having to refresh the page.

I get type errors whenever `img` is followed

```
  <Typography className={classes.imageTypographyTitle} variant="h4" align="center">{img.image_title}</Typography> 
               <Divider className={classes.imageDivider} variant="middle" />
               <Image image_url={img.img_url} />   
               <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.user.username}</Typography> 
               <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{moment(img.created_at).calendar()}</Typography> 
               ........
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'image_title' of undefined

On refresh i see the new data, and i can add data, and i can see the updated array. The type error only happens if the images array is empty.

I would like to append the data to the empty array, and show the data without re render/refresh or any type errors errors.

Should i use another lifecycle method ? because `componentWillMount` Cannot be called twice, just once. So given that array is empty, should i use something like `shouldComponentUpdate` to fetch the initial data ?

data structure given that their is existing data in the array.

```
0:{
  "id": 71,
  "image_title": "ii",
  "img_url": "https://*********",
  "created_at": "2019-06-24T02:36:48.359Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-06-24T02:36:48.359Z",
  "user_id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "googleId": null,
    "username": "a******",
    "password": "**********",
    "email": "a********",
    "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
  },
  "comments": []
}
```

**reducer**

```
import { GET_IMAGES, POST_COMMENT, DELETE_IMAGE, UPLOAD_IMAGE } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    images:[],

}

export default  (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_IMAGES:
            console.log(action.data);
            return{
                ...state,
                images:action.data
            }
        case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
            const newState = {...state}
            const myImages = newState.images 
            // console.log(myImages); // empty array
            const newImage = action.newImage
            console.log(newImage[0]); // gets the new uploaded image. 

            return {
                images:[

                    {
                        id: newImage[0].id,
                        user:{
                            username:newImage[0].user.username
                        },
                        comments:{
                          comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
                        },
                        image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
                        img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
                    },

                    myImages[0] // pass the previous images if array 
                                /// isn't empty

                ]   

            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**action**

```
// upload image 
export const uploadImage = data =>  {
   return (dispatch) => {
    Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
        const newImage = {...response.data}
        console.log(newImage);

        dispatch({type:UPLOAD_IMAGE, newImage})
        // history.push("/dashboard");
    });

   } 

}    
// get images
export const getImages = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
       const url =  await Axios.get('/images/uploads')
       const data = url.data;
        dispatch({ 
            type: GET_IMAGES,
            data
        })

    }
}
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import ImageContainer from "./ImageContainer"
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getImages, deleteImage, uploadImage} from '../actions/imageActions';
import dashboardStyles from '../styles/dashboardStyles';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {compose} from 'redux';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            image_url: '', 
            description:'',
            upload:false,
            isComment:false,
            comment_body:''
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        // console.log(this.state.description)
        // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
        this.props.uploadImage(data);

        this.setState({
            description: ''
        })



    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
        // console.log(this.state.description)
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getImages();
        console.log(this.props.image.images);
    }


      .........
      {image.images.length > 0 ? (
       image.images.map( (img, i) => (   
           <div key={i}>
               <ImageContainer img={img} deleteImg={() => this.deleteImg(img.id)}/>
           </div>      
       ))
      ) : (
          <div>
              <Grid item md={8}>
                  <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
               </Grid>
          </div>
      )}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   image: state.image
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   getImages: () => dispatch(getImages()),
   uploadImage: (data) => dispatch(uploadImage(data))
})
export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withStyles(dashboardStyles))(Dashboard)
```

**image container**

```
  render(){
       const { img, deleteImg, classes } = this.props
       return(
           <Grid item sm={12} md={12} className={classes.imageGridItem}>
               <Paper className={classes.imageContainerPaper}>
         {/* // empty image_title */}
               <Typography className={classes.imageTypographyTitle} variant="h4" align="center">{img.image_title}</Typography> 
               <Divider className={classes.imageDivider} variant="middle" />
               <Image image_url={img.img_url} />   
               <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.user.username}</Typography> 
               <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{moment(img.created_at).calendar()}</Typography> 
               ........                       
        </Grid>        
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Something doesn't look right. In your action-creator you pass newImage as an object, hence {...response.data} but then you use it as an array in your reducer; const newImage = action.newImage. then newImage[0]. You probably need to use [...response.data] instead

Comment: Hi Chris :) i tried that, and i got the same errors :(

Comment: wait i think something worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spread the existing images array inside your new state.

```
    case UPLOAD_IMAGE:
        const newState = {...state}
        const myImages = newState.images 
        // console.log(myImages); // empty array
        const newImage = action.newImage
        console.log(newImage[0]); // gets the new uploaded image. 

        return {
            images:[

                {
                    id: newImage[0].id,
                    user:{
                        username:newImage[0].user.username
                    },
                    comments:{
                      comment_body: newImage[0].comments.comment_body  
                    },
                    image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
                    img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
                },
                ...state.images

            ]   

        }
```

So with that you have a new state, with your new image first, followed by the initial images.

Comment: you mean `...state` ? using this.state doesn't work in redux.

Comment: let me give this a go.

Comment: Thanks man, heres the code, and heroku demo if you're interested in it. https://github.com/EliHood/ReactExpressPhotoShareApp

Comment: their is some things that im fixing, like only users can delete their posts, and passport-google issues that im having. but yeah thanks for your help Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Fix. remove this line.

```
myImages[0] // pass
```

Comment: this worked, however Chris another issue arises, i make a post, but it doesn't pass the prevState, or something. For example, say you have an array of 3 objects, and you make a post, all of the objects are removed from the UI, and i just see the data i just posted. But on refresh i see all the items with the array.

Comment: Gotcha, let me post an answer below to assist you. See my answer above/below lol

Comment: Hi @BARNOWL, did you figure out your question about redirecting?

Comment: im going to work on it tomorrow, going to bed, if i can' figure it out ill post a better worded question about it.

Comment: I was literally like 30 seconds away from providing you a solution haha. But for sure :). GN friend.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo i reopened the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747487/react-router-doesnt-re-render-after-history-push?noredirect=1#comment100053196_56747487