# react router doesn't re-render after history push

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm looking to re render/refresh, after a user has logged in, so im using `history.push` to do that.

```
import {history} from '../layout/Navbar'
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
    Axios.post('/users/login', userData)
        .then( res => {
            // retrieve token from the response 
            const token = res.data.token;
            // console.log(token);
            // pass the token in session
            sessionStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
            // set the auth token
            setAuthToken(token);

            // decode the auth token
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            // pass the decoded token
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))
            history.push('/dashboard');

        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(err.response.data){
                console.log(err.response)
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                })
            }
        })
}

export const getUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return Axios.get('/users/current_user',{
        }).then( res => {
            const data = res.data
            dispatch({type: GET_CURRENT_USER, data})
        })
    }
}

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded, dispatch) => {
    return{
        type:SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload:decoded,

    }

}
```

Instead it doesn't seem to re-render because im getting an error that only should have an error if a user isn't logged in.

For example

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

on one of my components.

On refresh on the dashboard page, the error goes away, so im looking for a way to re render the state, and redirect to dashboard that way a user will exist or throw an unauthorized error if given the wrong credentials.

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from '../components/PrivateRoute';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Login from '../components/Login';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {logoutUser} from '../actions/authActions';
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

// import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

class Navbar extends Component {
    logout = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logoutUser();

    }
    render() {
        // LINKS
        const authLinks = (
            <span>
                <Button>
                    <Link to="/dashboard" color="primary">
                        Dashboard
                    </Link>
                </Button>       
                <Button onClick={this.logout} to="/">
                    <span>Logout</span>
                </Button>
            </span>

        );
        const guestLinks = (
            <span>
                <Button>
                    <Link to="/login">
                        Login
                    </Link>
                </Button>

                <Button>
                    <Link to="/signup">
                       Sign Up
                    </Link>

                </Button>
            </span>
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter history={history}>

                    <AppBar position="static">
                        <Toolbar>
                        <Grid justify="space-between" container >
                            <Typography variant="h6" style={{ color: '#fff'}}>
                               Image Upload App
                            </Typography>                         

                             {/* if is authenticated, will render authlinks 
                                if not will render guest links
                            */}
                            <Grid item>
                                <Button align="right">
                                    <Link style={{ color:'#fff'}} underline="none" to="/">
                                        Home
                                    </Link>
                                </Button>
                                 {this.props.auth.isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}

                            </Grid>




                        </Grid>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route exact path="/signUp" component ={SignUp}/>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/> {/* private routes for users who are authenticated */}
                        <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}></PrivateRoute>

                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    logoutUser: () => dispatch(logoutUser())
})
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Navbar)
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import setAuthToken from "./actions/utils/setAuthToken";
import Navbar from './layout/Navbar';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import store from './store';
import {setCurrentUser, logoutUser, getUser } from './actions/authActions';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

// JWT TOKEN
if (sessionStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(sessionStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(sessionStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  store.dispatch( getUser());

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {

    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/login";
  }



}
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Navbar/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Login**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {loginUser, googleLogin } from '../actions/authActions';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { GoogleLoginButton} from "react-social-login-buttons";
import LoginForm from './LoginForm/LoginForm';
import {history} from '../layout/Navbar';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// const onSuccess = response => console.log(response);
// const onFailure = response => console.error(response);
class Login extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            formData:{
                username:'',
                password:'',
                isAuthenticated: false,
            },
            errors:{}
        }
    }
    logInGithub = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('hello');
        this.props.githubLogin();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(this.props.auth);
        if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
          this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
        }
      }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated){
            this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {formData} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            formData: {
                ...formData,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        });
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {formData} = this.state;
        const {username, password} = formData;
        const creds = {
            username,
            password
        }
        this.props.loginUser(creds,  this.props.history);


        // console.log(creds);
    }
    render(){
        const googleLogin = response => {
            let googleData;
            googleData = {
              googleID: response.profileObj.googleId,
              email: response.profileObj.email,
            //   password: "",
            };
            console.log(googleData);
            this.props.googleLogin(googleData);
          };
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={0}>
                <Grid item  sm={10} md={6} lg={4} style={{ margin:'20px 0px'}}>
                <Typography variant="h4" style={{ letterSpacing: '2px'}} >
                     Sign In
                </Typography>
                {this.props.auth.errors ? (
                    this.props.auth.errors.map( (err, i) => (
                        <div key={i} style={{color: 'red' }}>
                            {err} 
                        </div>
                    ))                  
                ):(
                    null
                )}
                <LoginForm 
                    mySubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    myChange={this.handleChange}
                    username={this.state.username}
                    password={this.state.password}
                />
                    <Grid item sm={12}>
                            <Typography align="center" variant="h4" style={{ letterSpacing: '6px'}} >
                                OR
                            </Typography>
                        <Divider style={{ width: '200px', margin:'20px auto', backgroundColor:'#000000'}} variant="middle" />
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
Login.propTypes = {
    loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    loginUser: (userData) => dispatch(loginUser(userData)),
    googleLogin: (userData) => dispatch(googleLogin(userData))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Login))
```

Comment: um why are you using history.push why not just use <Redirect /> from react router?

Comment: Does that work in a redux action ?

Comment: you dont have to write that in the redux action.... you can call the redux action and then call <Redirect/> depending on the login success or failure

Comment: Error is something else and not with `history.push`. post a complete error so that we can see where is it failing.

Comment: @BARNOWL Try wrapping the component that needs to be re-rendered in `withRouter()` from react-router: `export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Navbar))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So it appears that i wasn't using the navbar `history`,

so instead of  `this.props.history.push("/dashboard")`

I used `history.push('/dashboard')`

**Login.js**

```
  .....
  componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(this.props.auth);
        if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
          history.push("/dashboard");
        }
      }
   componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated){
            history.push("/dashboard")
        }
    }
```

**Navbar.js**

and change this

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory()
```

to this

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({forceRefresh:true})
```

This is without using `withRouter()` instances.

I still had to remove `history.push` from the `authActions.js` `loginUser` function.

Comment: @Christopher if their is a better approach or cleaner approach let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening is the `push` to your `Dashboard` component is executing before the `setCurrentUser()` action has time to complete.

```
dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded))
history.push('/dashboard');
```

These two lines of code are running to execution, not synchronously (one after the other) as it may appear.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

This likely comes from your `Dashboard` component. You're probably using something like `this.props.auth.user` in some capacity, where `this.props.auth` is not yet valid.

We can configure your code to have a more synchronous flow of actions.

You're probably calling the `loginUser()` action-creator inside your
**Login** component (makes sense). Let's make sure we bring in `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and the `auth-state` from your reducer at the minimum. By bringing in those two, we can have the redirect handled in `componentDidUpdate()`

So at the minimum the **Login** component will use the following imports and life-cycle methods like so:

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/authActions"
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

class Login extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated){
            this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.auth.isAuthenticated){
            this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
        }
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const userData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        this.props.loginUser(userData)
     }

    render(){
        return(
           ...yourmarkup
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        auth: state.auth
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loginUser: (userData) => {
            dispatch(loginUser(userData))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Login))
```

Note, in your **authActions** file, we can remove the `history.push("/dashboard")` line, since we are calling the redirect from the `Login` component.

**The synchronous flow would be:**

1. You submit the login form inside `Login` component, calling your
   `loginUser()` action-creator.
2. `loginUser` executes, it dispatches `setCurrentUser` and we pass in the
   decoded user.
3. Your reducer returns a new state, now using the authenticated user.
4. `Login` component receives new props from the redux-store, causing
   the component to re-render.
5. `componentDidUpdate()` is triggered, we verify that the
   **auth-state** has an authenticated user. If true, we redirect to the `Dashboard` component.

Comment: will give this a shot, and let you know how it went thanks chris.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but this still give the same error. I updated code to show Login component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use withRouter hoc and then use props.history -

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const Navbar = props => {
   return (
     <div onClick={() => props.history.push('your-path')}>
        Navigate to your-path
     </div>
   )
}

export default withRouter(Navbar)
```

Comment: The withRouter component must be *within* a <Router> or Router-derived component such as <MemoryRouter>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using 'React > 16.8.0' and functional components.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

Use in your functional component:

```
const history = useHistory();
history.push('/dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a [compatibility issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804) between the latest ReactRouter (5.2) and the latest `history` (5.0).

One of the symptoms of this incompatibility is `history.push()` calls not triggering a re-render. Downgrading `history` to v4 should fix the problem.